# How would I go about evaluating $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{{-u}^{2}}\cos(ux)du$?

Tags: calculus, integration

So I had this question as extra credit on my exam and no one was able to solve it.

I tried to do integration by parts but that just keep on expanding with no solution in sight.

I have also tried to take the derivative of the integral but that didn't seem to help either.

How would I integrate $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{{-u}^{2}}\cos(ux)du$?

Comment: Do you know any complex analysis?

Comment: If by complex analysis you mean [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_analysis) then no.